What does 増やさんとって mean here?

This is the first sentence of the sequence... therefor not much context.
"At Christmas..."
I'm not sure how to take 増やさんとって here?  増やさん seems to be a negative but I don't imagine it's "I told you to increase my work at Christmas"

It means 増やさないで "Don't increase; Don't add". The character is probably speaking in Kansai-ben, or some dialect in the west (西日本):

クリスマスに仕事増やさんとってよ。
≈ クリスマスに仕事を増やさないでよ。


～ない → ～ん
～でいて → ～といて → ～とって

In Kansai-ben (or Kyoto-ben at least) we often say 「～せんといて。・～しんといて。」(＜～しないでいて) (rather than ～せんで。) in daily speech to mean 「～しないで。」"Don't do ~~".
